# How to enable launching of the app from deep link in Safari iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, deep-linking, url-scheme

My boss asked me to enable deep linking in a Objective-C app but I don't know that language. First, I enabled URL schemes in `info.plist`:

[image]

then in my `AppDelegate.m` I have:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2]; //add 2 seconds longer.

    // Do your time consuming setup

    [splashView removeFromSuperview];

    _pushDict= nil;
    [self APNSRegistration];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    //[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber =0;
    // Assign tab bar item with titles
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem4 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem5 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4];

    tabBarItem1.title = @"";
    tabBarItem2.title = @"";
    tabBarItem3.title = @"";
    tabBarItem4.title = @"";
    tabBarItem5.title = @"";
    NSString *badgeValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber];
    if([badgeValue  isEqual: @"0"]) badgeValue = nil;
    tabBarItem3.badgeValue = badgeValue;

    //unselected
    [tabBarItem1 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"0003-home3.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [tabBarItem1 setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"0003-home3_selected.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    //unselected
    [tabBarItem2 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"tazza.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [tabBarItem2 setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"0163-mug_selected.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    //unselected
    [tabBarItem3 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"0084-calendar.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [tabBarItem3 setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"0084-calendar_selected.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    //unselected
    [tabBarItem4 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"0016-camera.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [tabBarItem4 setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"0016-camera_selected.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    //unselected
    [tabBarItem5 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"0072-location.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [tabBarItem5 setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"0072-location_selected.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];

    NSDictionary *pushDict = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

    _pushDict= pushDict;
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options {
    printf("openURL called");
    return YES;
}
```

If from iOS Safari I launch the URL `superbar://` it says that Safari cannot open the page.
I am sure I am missing something in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, but what?

Answer (score 1):

Simply type `superbar://` in safari adress bar.
App should launch.
Please check in your info tab -> URL Types

Comment: it does not work. As I said iOS Safari says that it cannot launch/find the page

Comment: Once you have added a URL scheme to your info.plist, it *should* at least launch your app regardless of the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` configuration. Are you sure you have the correct bundle ID set in URL Identifier?

Comment: Also go to the Info tab in the Xcode project. Check URL Types. Ensure that the identifier and URL scheme you select are unique.